# Redirect users according to country -HTACCESS?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

. Consider my domain name is www.example.com . It is in english

And i have have one language version for dutch   www.example.com/nl

I want to redirect url to www.example.com/nl only for people requesting from Netherland.

My website is in shared hosting.  How can i achieve this ?

Comment: Googling `Redirect users according to country` gives some promising results, including answers on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5):

You can redirect based on the browser's language setting coming from the user:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-language} nl [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /nl [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I like this, a handy thing to know, I guess a browser's language settings are less likely to be incorrect than an IP check?

Comment: Yes. There are several advantages. One you are allowing the user to tell you their preference. So if you have an American living in Holland he will still see the site in English. Second, this approach is far faster than IP lookup which will slow your site down.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use GeoIP service and determine country of your visitor and then do the proper redirect.

Download Geo API for PHP here http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/api/php/

There are samples how to use the code.

It would be something like

```
include("geoipcity.inc");
include("geoipregionvars.php");

$gi = geoip_open("/usr/local/share/GeoIP/GeoIPCity.dat",GEOIP_STANDARD);
$record = geoip_record_by_addr($gi,$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

if ( $record->country_code == "NL" ) {
    header('Location: http://www.yoursite.com/nl');
}
```

Comment: Geo API for PHP link not working. i know the answer is old.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the apache module mod_geoIP, might do what you want, but otherwise you're going to have to rely on a script to get the geolocation information and redirect based on that.

As a side topic, IP lookup isn't 100% accurate in regards to getting geolocation information, so be careful. Often it is a better idea to let the user choose first time round, and then save a cookie to remember this choice.

Edit: And yes @Pekka has a good point, there is tons of information about it on Google.